# Problems aligning a Youtube clip centrally in an Android WebView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display a YouTube clip embedded in a WebView in Android with the size of the web view as large as 640x360 dip and in the center of a tablet's screen. I've managed to do this, however the YouTube clip seems to be cut off and a white background gets displayed as in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the Java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class VideoWebViewActivity extends Activity {


    private static final int VIDEO_WIDTH = 640; 
    private static final int VIDEO_HEIGHT = 360;
    private WebView webView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.weblink_webview);

        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(final WebView view, final int errorCode, final String description, final String failingUrl) {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }
        });

        String youtubeUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/O1N2rENXq_Y";

        String embedCode = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" + " <style type=\"text/css\"> body { background-color: transparent; padding:0; margin:0; }</style>"
                        + "</head><body><div align=\"center\"><iframe align=\"middle\" width=\"" + (VIDEO_WIDTH) + "\" height=\""
                        + (VIDEO_HEIGHT) + "\" src=\"" + youtubeUrl
                        + "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></body></html>";


        webView.loadData(embedCode, "text/html", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (webView != null) {
            webView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And here is the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/weblink"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible" >


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/weblink_webview"
        android:layout_width="640dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: The strangest thing about this, is that on a 7 inch tablet with Android 3.2 it works fine, however on a 10 inch tablet with 4.0.3 (ICS) it looks like in the screen shot.Same issue on a 10 inch tablet with Honeycomb 3.1. This leads me to believe that there is some kind of a setting/problem within the web view itself that causes this behaviour.

Edit 2: While trying various ideas to solve the problem, we noticed that the white rectangle over the right side of the clip seems to have it's size in direct link with the amount of left margin you add to the web view. For example, if we would give up centering the view and add an 100dip margin, we would get an approximately 100dip wide white strip on the clip's right.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks,

Mihai

Comment: have you tried setting: layout_width="wrap_content" ?

Comment: yep, I tried that, however I get 2 white horizontal rectangles to the right and left of the clip that reach to the screen edges and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

this post is a bit old, but if you are still looking for a solution:

Webview on the ICS are very buggy, and your problem is the same with a google map in a WebView with a left margin.

To resolve this problem, in the manifest, I changed

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

by

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

This allows not to activate the new features of ICS and solve the problem

Cheers

Comment: Indeed, there seems to be a bug with the WebView (confirmed that at Google I/O this year) in ICS, and it also seems to be fixed in Jelly Bean. Thanks for the answer, I am going to try it out, however we'll need to support newer APIs in our app, so this limitation may not work for us.